# Method variables in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

When I write `ActiveRecord` models in rails I want to make sure that local variables I use in my method will remain local to the scope of the method I write, and I will not be accidentally overwriting model property in future.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :do_something

  def do_something
    # ... some logic
    group = "some value"
    # ... more logic 
  end    
end
```

How do I make sure that if I happen to add `group` property to my model in future - my method will not accidentally overwrite it?

I thought about class variables, but it's not what they are for, and I think using them will be a bad practice.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? to get some kind of exception if this situation occurs or just to know the list of model attributes to put some conditionals around all local variables assignments by hands?

Comment: @twonegatives i just want my method variable be of separate scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby you can define local variables and instance variables with the same name.

```
class Example
  @instance = 4

  def example_method
    @instance += 1
  end

  def example_2
    instance = 0
    10.times { instance += 1 }
  end
end

e = Example.new

e.example_2 # => 10
e.instance # => 4
e.example_method # => 5
e.instance # => 5
```

these will not conflict

#### example_2

is returning the local variable which is then destroyed if not used

#### example_method

is setting the instance variable which will save per instance of the class or in this case for active record will save to database.

Also note you can be more explicit when referring to instance variables and say

`self.instance`

#### EDIT

your `group` variable inside your `do_something` is a local variable and will not cause conflict with `@group` which is a instance variable of a higher scope

#### EDIT2

I have a projects model in my application

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_NAME_REGEX = /(\A[\w ]+)/
  VALID_URL_REGEX = URI::regexp(["http", "https"])

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                 :uniqueness => true,
               :length => {
                  :maximum => 24
               },
           :format => {
             :with => VALID_NAME_REGEX,
             :message => "Only allow numbers letters hyphens and underscores"
         }

  after_save :test
  def test
    name = 'bob'
  end
end
```

after setting my model to this and creating a new instance of it on my website I can confirm this will not set my projects name to `bob`

Comment: Yes, but in case of `ActiveRecord` models (see my example) - model properties are not class variables

Comment: none of these are class variables. @@ is a class variable, @ is an instance variable and a variable without either is a local variable. In the case of active record model properties are instance variables which you can refer to with an @ or self.

Comment: Sorry, that's what i meant, instance variable. My point is - if i use local method variable (no @ prefixes) and then define column with the same name in my database table for that model - here comes trouble.

Comment: @Anri im updating my answer with my test. It will not affect your database if you use an local variable in your method

Comment: Got it, thanks, seems like i need to read more on ruby scoping.

Comment: It can be a bit confusing, [here](http://www.eriktrautman.com/posts/ruby-explained-inheritance-and-scope) is a good url

Comment: The code example in your answer throws a NoMethodError and also the @instance = 4 does not initialise the variable. I know that wasn't the point of the question but still when you provide a code sample you should at least make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using a local variable, that is a variable not prefixed by @ or @@ will not cause a namespace collision with future model attributes.  Those attributes would have to be referenced in such a way similar to `self.group`.  You could run into trouble if your code in your model tweaks the class by adding fields or members to the object at runtime, or if you mess with the class definition, but just declaring a local variable in a method will not collide with an instance variable that corresponds to an ORM field.

Additionally, if you've got methods to mutate fields in your model and you try to access them by saying

```
def getgroup
  group
end
```

this won't work, either.  `group` in this context is undefined, because it doesn't refer to anything else in the local scope

Comment: Thanks for confirmation I don't know why my lonng drawn out answer wasn't enough, scoping is quite clear in ruby and I doubt that rails would override the normal scoping